# Avada Fusion - Top nav menu aligned left

Tags: css, navbar

I'm using one of Avada themeforest themes. I'm trying to build a very basic website identical to this in layout. I can't figure out how to get the top menus to the left next to my logo and ideally would like a very simplistic hover menu function rather than some elaborate accordian.

I've tried adding CSS within fusion builder / wordpress but to no avail.

here's my inspiration:

http://caralimccall.com/

thanks and any help would be great!!

Comment: please include the code what you have done.

Comment: here is the URL of what i've done. As you can see the top nav menu is aligned right.  http://www.livesdowntheroad.org/